# what is advantage of .ini file when set db connect (winform)

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ini

I am now involved in a small c# project on winform (just 2-3 select statements), 
and the project need to connect to mssql. 
I know there are many ways to connect DB. 
but why people use .ini or xml file to connect DB? 
Is not good insert connect statement(server, id, pw ...) to class?

Comment: It's because they want to change the connection string without need to rebuild the application. If you put the connection string in source code of your classes, then if you want to use a different user/password or servername to connect to database, you need to rebuild the application. Also it's better to avoid using `.ini` files or custom xml files as a settings holder. Use `appsettings` in `app.config` or a `Settings.settings` file.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I got it. thank a lot.

Comment: also if you have the connection string in an xml file, and your database information changes, like table name, you only need to open the xml file and change information there for the connection to work against the changed database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to use Configuration file (.ini, .xml) if you want to change connection string later. If you put your data in your code, everytime you change it, you must re-compile your code.